# Problems saving a firebase database with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

i've been using Firebase for a couple of months now, and it's been great along with angularjs and anfularfire, before i explain the problem, let me give you a fast background: i am currently using different controllers for an app that is meant for users to register plant species and to use them as items to create an interactive garden. In order to save the database from any controller, i stored the reference into the $scope

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
$scope.database = $firebaseObject(rootRef)
```

so when i want to make a change or add an object, i do it like this:

```
$scope.example_function = function(i){//supposing 'i' is a string
    $scope.element[e] = i //supposing that 'e' contains a string 
    $scope.database.$save()
}
```

Sometimes this works, other times it just doesn't save the firebase, specially when editing existing objects inside the database or adding an element to an specific object. It's really frustrating because it doesn't throw an error or something, i even tried deleting the path i wanted to change and then storing it again with the new info. Also i tried with local references to the database in each controller, but nope... Anyone knows how else can i make this work?

Also. I am pretty sure the connection between the database and the app is fine, i got to store lots of species by now, the problem is when i want to edit the info from the species or add an url to get an image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to bind your entire database to a the scope. It will be extremely hard to scale.

Remember that when you request for a ref and send it to `$firebaseObject` it will register to change events and this will start sync of your entire database which might potentially be huge.

For the issues you're experiencing, it looks like you're binding the database reference to a `database` property of `$scope` but in your `example_function` you're applying values to  an `element` property. So maybe the fix you're looking for is something like:

```
function example_function(i) {
  $scope.database.element = i;
  $scope.database.$save();
}
```